# adding a new div iff there is any input in a form

Tags: javascript

I made a form with some java script. Now, I want to add a new line "player"(div id players) when there is an input in one of the both fields. I'm a real starter with java script and hope somebody can help me with some "simple" explanation so I can understand what's happening. (the embedded script is also from somebody else:))

Thanks in advanced.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <ul id="ul_stappen">
                <li id="step_1" class="selected">step_1</li>
                <li id="step_2" class="">step_2</li>
                <li id="step_3" class="">step_3</li>
                <li id="step_4" class="">step_4</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="div_stappen">
                <div id="content_step_1" class="content_step" style="display: block;">content step 1</div>
                <div id="content_stap_2" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 2</div>
                <div id="content_stap_3" class="content_step" style="display: none;">content step 3</div>
                <div id="content_stap_4" class="content_step" style="display: none;">
                    <div id="players">
                        <label for="name_1">Name player 1</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name_1" id="name_1" autocomplete="off" value="">
                        <label for="email_1">Email player</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email_1" id="email_1" autocomplete="off" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        $('#ul_stappen>li').on('click',function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('#div_stappen>div').filter(function(){return $(this).css('display')==='block'}).hide();
            $('#div_stappen>div').eq($(this).index()).show();   
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: tag this to JavaScript

Comment: done :) thnx @Aragorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you will need to listen to the `.change()` event of the inputs. Then test if the last `player` is not empty (to avoid adding players everytime an `input` changes) and append the new player's inputs, taking care of the name, text and id according to the number of the new player.

Here is the code:

```
$('#players').on('change', 'input', function () {
    var last_player = $('.player').length;
    var next_player = last_player + 1;

    if ($('#name_' + last_player).val() == '' && $('#email_' + last_player).val() == '') {
        return false;
    }
    var $new_player = $('<div class="player"></div>');

    $new_player.append('<label for="name_' + next_player + '">Name player ' + next_player + '</label>');
    $new_player.append('<input type="text" name="name_' + next_player + '" id="name_' + next_player + '" autocomplete="off" value="">');
    $new_player.append('<label for="email_' + next_player + '">Email player ' + next_player + '</label>');
    $new_player.append('<input type="text" name="email_' + next_player + '" id="email_' + next_player + '" autocomplete="off" value="">');

    $('#players').append($new_player);
});
```

And a working [<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/o65p4g4v/1)

By the way, I don't think that this is the best way to do this. Generally is better to add some `add` and `remove` icons next to each player.

Comment: Thnx @alvaro this is just what i needed :)

Comment: Strange thing happen, and i hope u know the answer -->
when i start whit 
$("#players").append('<div>'); 
....
....
$("#players").append('</div>');

The output is that the div's are togheter whitout all the appends inbetween but afther....

Comment: When you use `.append()` jQuery automatically closes the HTML tag. So when you do `$("#players").append('<div>');` it is actually the same that `$("#players").append('<div></div>');`. Maybe something like `.wrap()` will suit you better.

Comment: could u make a example for me whit .wrap()?
I treid a couple of things but still no effect :(
it's aftherall the main question afther all :)

Comment: Couldyou clarify me what are you trying to do now? What are you exactly trying to append and where?

Comment: adding the complete (div id=players) in the original question.
(maybe it's better to make it (div class=players) :)

Comment: I think it would make more sense if there is a parent div with id `players` and inside there are 1 or more divs with class `player`. This way you would have a group of players contained in a container called players... an that makes a lot of sense. Let me know if this is what you want.